# Wrap multiple repeating elements into same container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a container that contain multiple repeating  with same two class: First, second
like below.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="first"></span>
    <span class="second"></span>
    <span class="first"></span>
    <span class="second"></span>
    <span class="first"></span>
    <span class="second"></span>
    <span class="first"></span>
    <span class="second"></span>
</div>
```

I want to group this two span two by two in a new div with specific id: new (for example)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="new">
        <span class="first"></span>
        <span class="second"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="new">
        <span class="first"></span>
        <span class="second"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="new">
        <span class="first"></span>
        <span class="second"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="new">
        <span class="first"></span>
        <span class="second"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I do

```
var evens = $("#wrapper > span:even");
var odds = $("#wrapper > span:odd");
var i = 0;
odds.each(function () {
  $(this).add(evens[i]).wrapAll('<span clas="good" style="background-color: red; margin-bottom:40px;"></span>');
  i++;
});
```

What is the best way to do this purpose in jQuery, using name of the class (first, second) and not even and odd ?

Comment: Where did you get stuck, what did you try? When you searched for examples did none of those work for you for some reason, were there any errors? Also: multiple elements sharing the same `id` attribute will always cause problems in JavaScript (an `id` ***must*** *be unique within the document*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#wrapper .first").each((i, el) => {
  $(el).nextUntil(".first").addBack().wrapAll(`<div class="wrap" />`)
});
```

```css
#wrapper .wrap {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="first">1</span>
    <span class="second">2</span>
    <span class="first">1</span>
    <span class="second">2</span>
    <span class="first">1</span>
    <span class="second">2</span>
    <span class="third">3</span>
    <span class="first">1</span>
    <span class="second">2</span>
</div>
```